# Fechar portas que se iniciam ao ligar o sistema

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Bom dia,

Estou utilizando Ubuntu 20.10, estou com o problema de que sempre quando inicio o computador, está iniciando com certas portas ainda abertas, como a do ssh, http, postgresql e ipp. Há alguma configuração que não permita elas iniciarem ao iniciar? (Creio que quando iniciei elas, elas ficaram permanente, porem não sei o por que de ser tao direto assim..). Só consigo fechá-las a mao, ou seja, dando um stop no service de cada, estas eu acabei abrindo em certos momentos para utilizar, porem não desejo que fiquem sempre abertas quando inicio o pc.
Sei que posso criar um script para fechar de grosso modo porem nao acho que seja a solução mais recomendada, enfim, alguem consegue ajudar?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, sua pergunta não é diretamente relacionada à programação e não é apropriada para esse site, existe outro site da rede que pode te ajudar, o [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colocando de outro modo, me parece que o que você deseja é impedir que determinados serviços (ou daemons) incializem automaticamente. Se você não usa esse serviços com frequência, de fato, isso é uma boa idéia.
Para selecionar os serviços que deseja desativar, você pode:

**Modo Gráfico**

Aperte a tecla Super (ou Windows) e digite "Aplicativos". Já deve aparecer o atalho para o aplicativo "Aplicativos de Sessão" (ou, se a instalação estiver em inglês, procure por "Startup Applications" ou algo parecido). Nesse aplicativo, você pode selecionar o que gostaria de iniciar junto com o boot do sistema ou não.

O Dio Linux escreveu um artigo sobre isso, também:

https://diolinux.com.br/tutoriais/desative-servicos-que-inicializam-junto.html

**Modo Texto**

Há aplicações similares para a mesma tarefa, no modo texto. Uma delas, é o rcconf. Já não o uso a bastante tempo, mas creio que ele ainda esteja disponível nos repositório do Ubuntu. Para instalar e executá-lo, abra o aplicativo terminal (ou alterne para uma console virtual, usando CTRL+ALT+F1 a F6) e digite:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
sudo rcconf
```

Obs.: o comando *sudo* vai pedir que você digite a sua senha senha de usuário, para permitir a instalação e execução do aplicativo.

Espero que isso ajude.